# copyNextSampleBuffer after application returns from background on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, video, background

I'm reading a video file using:

```
CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer = [asset_reader_output copyNextSampleBuffer];
```

where `asset_reader_output` is an instance of `AVAssetReaderTrackOutput`  class.

this works well, but if the application goes to the background and then returns (for instance, if a phone call was received), then after returning to the application, copyNextSampleBuffer always return nil.

why is it returning nil and not the actual data? how can i solve this problem?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974679/memory-problems-with-avassetwriterinput-requestmediadatawhenreadyonqueueusingb/10526993#10526993

Answer (score 0):

try to track on current sample buffer. Then, in your appDelegate class, you have callback methods applicationDidEnterBackground and applicationWillEnterForeground. just set current semple buffer marker at right place before calling copyNextSampleBuffer

Comment: Could you give an example with code?