# AVAssetReaderTrackOutput copynextsamplebuffer || always NULL after return from background

Tags: ios, video, background, avassetreader

This is familiar with my question but I didn't understand the answer: [copyNextSampleBuffer after application returns from background on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816641/copynextsamplebuffer-after-application-returns-from-background-on-iphone)

I'm just trying to use an AVAssetReaderTrackOutput to read a video:

```
CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer = [trackOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];
```

Everything works fine, but when my app returns from background the sampleBuffer is always NULL and the assetReader is in state 3 which is the failure state I guess. Reading state would be 1.

How to solve this?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974679/memory-problems-with-avassetwriterinput-requestmediadatawhenreadyonqueueusingb/10526993#10526993

Comment: @Max did u check time-stamp of copyNextSampleBuffer